# Find a closed form solution for the following sequence 1,2,1,3,2,4,2,6,3,8,3,12

Tags: closed-form

I need help with this problem.

Find a closed form solution for the following sequence 1,2,1,3,2,4,2,6,3,8,3,12

Comment: I can't really identify what the sequence is supposed to be to begin with.

Comment: [This](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=interpolating+polynomial(1,2,1,3,2,4,2,6,3,8,3,12)) works.

$$\small a_n=\frac{239 n^{11}}{3628800} - \frac{941 n^{10}}{201600} + \frac{15121 n^9}{103680} - \frac{106627 n^8}{40320} + \frac{4142051 n^7}{134400} - \frac{6953329 n^6}{28800} + \frac{937219637 n^5}{725760} - \frac{189056173 n^4}{40320} + \frac{1457296303 n^3}{129600} - \frac{846796739 n^2}{50400} + \frac{35016917 n}{2520} - 4727$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to be of the form $1,2,1,3,\ldots,k,2^k,k,3\cdot 2^{k-1},\ldots$.  However, there are infinitely many sequences with "reasonably good definitions" which start with a given finite subsequence.  The sequence given by projectilemotion is a perfectly good one.